# Putting number inside int but not summing it

Tags: c, integer

I want to put some numbers in my integer but I don't want to sum them, for example:
I have `int car = 500;` and I want to add a digit `5` at end of it, but I don't want to sum `500` and `5`, I want it to look like `5005`. How I can do that?

Comment: `car = car * 10 + 5`

Comment: That you're asking this question (that you want to add a digit onto the end of the representation of the number, not add to the VALUE of the number) suggests that while you're storing it as an int, you're thinking of it more as a string than a number.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Only works for digits <10
int new_digit = 5;

// "Shift" the current value 1 digit left.
car *= 10;

// Append the new digit
car += new_digit;
```

The other thing to consider: If you need to manipulate numbers like that, is `int` the correct data type? perhaps you would be better off with a string?

Comment: Yap, thanks! I figured out that this is best way for stuff that I imagined. But in reality I found out that arrays are better for this job! Thanks one more time!

Answer (score 1):

doesn't it will be as simple as follows?

```
int car = 500;
car *= 10;  //adding another digit -> 5000
car += 5;  // add that 5 -> 5005
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have shown you how to do this by doing math, by multiplying by 10.  Depending on your needs, you could also do it using strings, like this:

```
int car = 500;
int newdigit = 5;
char carstr[10], suffix[10], newstr[20];

snprintf(carstr, 10, "%d", car);
snprintf(suffix, 10, "%d", newdigit);

strcpy(newstr, carstr);
strcat(newstr, suffix);

printf("%s\n", newstr);

/* or you can convert new digit string back to int */

int newnum = atoi(newstr);
printf("%d\n", newnum);
```

If you go this road, of course, you have to always be careful to make the character arrays big enough to hold the strings you're storing in them.  For production code, many people recommend not using functions like `strcpy` and `strcat` at all, because it's simply too easy to end up overflowing the underlying character arrays.

Comment: Why not simply use `snprintf(newstr, sizeof newstr, "%d%d", car, newdigit);` ?